# au plus près / de plus près - what's the difference?

Tags: sens

"En regardant **au plus près** la photo"

"En regardant **de plus près** la photo"

Are they interchangeable completely?

Answer (score 2):

"Au plus près" means "At the closest range possible", while "de plus près" means "closer than where you actually are".

*Je veux être au plus près de toi* - *I want to be the closest to you*
*Je veux te voir de plus près* - *I want to see you from closer*

I don't think they can be changed on demand, they both have their own signification.